# Creating named semaphore at runtime

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my application, Im creating several data sets, that need to be locked. I wanted to implement a mechanism that would create semaphore for each data set (so that different data sets could be accessed concurrently).
The problem is that when I try to create semaphore in one class like that:

```
new Semaphore(1, 1, $@"Global\{UniqueId}");
```

and than I check for its existence in different class like that (with the same unique ID):

```
Semaphore.TryOpenExisting($@"Global\{UniqueId}", out semaphore)
```

its not working - the second class is not able to open it (thinking it doesnt exist).

When I tried to switch to single semaphore, something like that:

```
new Semaphore(1, 1, @"Global\Foo", out created);
```

it was working fine and the second class was able to open it.

Is there something wrong with my approach?

I even tried to use string intern for the name like this:

```
string.Intern($@"Global\{UniqueId}")
```

But it did not helped.

I also tried to put Thread.Sleep() after creating semaphore in the first class, cause I thought, that maybe the second class in not able to find it, cause its not written in the system yet or something - but still no luck.

Additional notes: I need semaphore because of being able to enter the lock in one thread and release it in another.
Also, this thing is happening on self hosted WCF service - Im not sure whether this could cause any problems.

---

**UPDATE:**

What actualy helped was creating List in the first class and storing each created semaphore in it. The problem is not occuring anymore after this.

Still I dont understand why - I wasnt calling `.Dispose()` or `.Close()` on semaphore anywhere and from what I read in documentation, unless I call these methods, the semaphore should still be available.

Comment: What is the actual value of `{UniqueId}` ?

Comment: Its GUID, in my application, its in this form: "942e6892_9c71_4fe0_8938_49a3bb9e292b"

Comment: If you were not keeping a persistent reference to the semaphore created in the first class, it may have been getting garbage collected, which would close it.

Comment: Yes, that would explain why the change described in my post under Update worked. But I dont understand why the first method (using name "Global\Foo" worked without storing any reference to the semaphore.

Comment: Hard to be sure, but note that the code sample you gave for the "Global\Foo" version has the `out created` argument, which is not in your GUID-based code sample. I suspect there is a difference between the two versions that would explain the different behavior.